# IE 8 Page height Issue

Tags: css

I have web page working properly on Ie 7 and mozilla but when opened in IE 8 height getting mizimized.Is there any additional height property i need to set up for this in css??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have a float issue. Are you floating elements? If so, you might want to put clear: both as a css property in your footer.

The height depends on a couple of things, such as how you have initially set it (`%`, `px`), and how it is positioned. If the height is set with pixels then you should be ok.

A fallback option is to use `min-height: 800px;` replacing 800 with your chosen value. That way if something happens to the content (or there is none), you will still see the element.

Also, if the element in question is not meant to have any content, then give it `display: block;`.